# Getting Integer value from Instance in Z3

Tags: casting, z3, sat

My code is

```
def test():
    s = Solver()
    a = Int('x')
    b = Int('y')
    s.add(a*b==22)
    print s.check()
    return s.model()[a], s.model()[b]
```

This will print numbers, but when you see `type(s.model()[a])` or `type(s.model()[b])` it will give `<type 'instance'>` . How to cast it in a way it will return `<type 'int'>` ? I cannot use the return type into my code any further as it returned instance even though if you `print s.model()[a]` it will *look* like a integer but it isn't.

Answer (score 6):

Simply use the `as_long` method. That is, replace the last line in your function with:

```
   return s.model()[a].as_long(), s.model()[b].as_long()
```